# Why GCC warns me to start main function argument with integer data type?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm trying to get an argument from the user through CLI. However, when I pass only string of characters...GCC warns me to start the first argument of main function with integer data type. Why is that and what is it for?

Comment: because that's how it must be done: arg count, then arg list.

Comment: Argument is int main(int argc, char* argv[]). It's has to be int for the first argument. Or else it will complain.

Comment: thanks got it! It's to count the number of arguments passed.:)